# Propositional Logic and Proofs

Tags: functional-programming, logic, coq, agda, proofs

I am trying to prove the below case for a homework assignment and have been working hours on it, still no luck.

[image: ((q, p) -> r) -> p -> q -> r]

Any suggestions or comments as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand...is there an error someplace...it all looks fine to me :-)  ---it looks like a correct paper-and-pencil proof, are you looking for a formalisation in Agda or something?

Answer (score 4):

This is how you'd prove it in Coq:

```
Coq < Theorem curry : forall p q r, ((q /\ p) -> r) -> p -> q -> r.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall (p q : Prop) (r : Type), (q /\ p -> r) -> p -> q -> r
```

First, we name all the premises:

```
curry < intros p q r f x y.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Type
  f : q /\ p -> r
  x : p
  y : q
  ============================
   r
```

The only premise that produces the subgoal `r` is `f`:

```
curry < apply f.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Type
  f : q /\ p -> r
  x : p
  y : q
  ============================
   q /\ p
```

To apply `f` we first need to satisfy the subgoals `q` and `p`:

```
curry < split.
2 subgoals

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Type
  f : q /\ p -> r
  x : p
  y : q
  ============================
   q

subgoal 2 is:
 p
```

The premise `y` is a proof for subgoal `q`:

```
curry < exact y.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Type
  f : q /\ p -> r
  x : p
  y : q
  ============================
   p
```

The premise `x` is a proof of subgoal `p`:

```
curry < exact x.
No more subgoals.
```

We're done. Here's the full proof:

```
curry < Qed.
intros p q r f x y.
apply f.
split.
 exact y.

 exact x.

curry is defined
```

In function programming languages like Haskell you'd have:

```
curry :: ((q, p) -> r) -> p -> q -> r
curry f x y = f (y, x)
```

Everything works out due to the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Answer (score 1):

We have a Coq proof thanks to @Aadit,
and it would only be fair ---ethical?--- to present an Agda proof.

An immediate and simple proof is

```
open import Data.Product

portation : {P Q R : Set} → (P × Q → R) → (P → Q → R)
portation P×Q→R = λ p q → P×Q→R (p , q)
```

Of course this may not at all be clear if the asker is not familiar with Agda and is seeking a formalisation. So let's throw in some detail!!

In constructive logic, propositions can be seen as the small types:

```
ℙrop = Set
```

Then pairing is the usual way to form conjugation,

```
data _∧_ (P Q : ℙrop) : Set where
 ∧I : P → Q → P ∧ Q
```

In constructive logic, implication is just function space: to say one thing implies another is tantamount to yielding a procedure that with input of the first kind returns output of the second kind.

```
_⇒_ : (P Q : ℙrop) → Set
_⇒_ = λ P Q → (P → Q)
```

Implication introduction is then just usual function-definition, and implication elimination is then nothing more than function application.

```
⇒I : ∀ {P Q} → (P → Q) → P ⇒ Q
⇒I P→Q = P→Q

⇒E : ∀ {P Q} → P ⇒ Q → P → Q
⇒E P→Q p = P→Q p
```

Now the asker is using natural-deduction style of proofs, so let us introduce some syntactic sugar to bridge the gap from the paper-and-pencil proof to the Agda formalisation.

```
syntax ⇒I {P} {Q} (λ p → q) = ⇒-I-assuming-proof p of P we-have Q proved-by q
```

Now the proof!

```
shunting : (P Q R : ℙrop) → (P ∧ Q) ⇒ R → P ⇒ (Q ⇒ R)
shunting P Q R P∧Q⇒R =
                    ⇒-I-assuming-proof p of P
                    we-have Q ⇒ R proved-by

                        ⇒-I-assuming-proof q of Q
                        we-have R proved-by

                            ⇒E P∧Q⇒R (∧I p q)
```

Which is not only quite readable, but also somewhat close to the asker's presentation!

*Agda is such a joy!*

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof using Klement's Fitch-style natural deduction proof checker and the *forallx* textbook providing explanation. (The links are below.)

[image]

The main problem with the original attempt is that lines 8 and 9 did not discharge the assumptions.  They appeared to stay in the same subproofs based on the indents and braces.

Otherwise the proof is the same as what I provided. On my line 6 I discharged the assumption I made of "Q" on line 3 by introducing the conditional (lines 3-5). On my line 7 I discharged the assumption "P" made on line 2 by introducing the conditional (lines 2-6).

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/